# Phosphorescent material

Tags: modeling, materials

File of pieces to look at what I'm working with: [image]

I've tried working on a plastic material that allows me to make my model realistic. I am trying to make a glow in the dark cube. The tricky part I have is that the internals can be seen either light or dark depending on if It's glowing or not. I've tried asking this in the past, but I think I've not been very specific as to what I'm asking.

As you can see there are parts darker than the rest of the face of each piece and when the cube is glowing those same parts now become lighter in color than the rest of the pieces.

I have those parts separate from the cube itself, thinking that it may help, but I'm not sure what I can do to get the look I'm trying to get. There is also a screw under the center cap that you can see when the light is on and when the light goes out it becomes dark in color also.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try a mix between *Diffuse, Transparent* and *Translucent*. As for the phosphorescence, I guess you need to use the *Emission Color* and put the *Emission Strength* at something around 0.5:

[image]

Comment: For some reason, it's not working for me. I assume it's because my cubes aren't one mesh arrayed like yours is, where you are able to see the darker rectangles even from the ones in the back row. My pieces are split up. For example, the faces of each cube piece separate from the main part. So for the corner piece the 3 faces you see are all separated as if it was a real cube and everything has a solidify modifier applied to it, so I assume that's why you are able to see straight through to the cubes in the back row.

Comment: I just uploaded my blend file. I hope that helps give you an idea of what I'm working with.